# My app works when run, but crashes on "apply changes and restart activity"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, kotlin, android-fragments

The app is supposed to be a simple google maps app, where I have 2 markers places in a map and zoom in on one of them. When I run the program, it works fine. But if I make a change in some code, and try to "apply changes to application and restart activity" it crashes. Sometimes I can edit my xml file and main file, save, then run it again to "bypass" the errors, but I want to know why the application keeps crashing :) Apologies for the big chunk of code, but I have no idea where the problem is. 
Here's the code:

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
package com.example.gpsworkingnew
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions

class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback{
    
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val gjovik = LatLng(60.784250, 10.686500)
        val gjovik2 = LatLng(60.784251, 10.687510)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(gjovik).title("Marker in gjovik"))
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(gjovik2).title("Marker in gjovik2"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(gjovik))
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(gjovik, 40f))

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error messages:**

```
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gpsworkingnew, PID: 7080
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gpsworkingnew/com.example.gpsworkingnew.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.gpsworkingnew:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.gpsworkingnew:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5456)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5362)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:58)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2076)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.gpsworkingnew:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.gpsworkingnew:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.gpsworkingnew:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060016 type #0x3 is not valid
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources.java:827)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.at.h(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):7)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fc.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):6)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bi.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):15)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.co.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):4)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):21)
        at cy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzH(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zad.zaa(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.java:1689)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1431)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3774)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:387)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:455)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:3468)
        at com.example.gpsworkingnew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5456)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5362)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:58)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2076)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7080 SIG: 9
```

Let  me know if I forgot to add  something :)

Comment: It only attempts to run your code instantly. Many types of code changes, especially resource changes cannot work without rebuilding the app.

Comment: @ElliotST have you found a solution? I sill need to clear app cache after occasitional applying code changes

Comment: @SergeyStasishin I'm sorry, been such a long time since I worked on the project I don't remember. I don't think I found the solution. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation here
https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes

It's says that

> Generally, you can use this option when you've modified code in the body of a method but you have not modified any resources

So if you add new ID or new resource like View or Viewgroup it won't be working

You can choose `Run` option if cannot be applied using either of the Apply Changes options